# Ascend HQL inheritance hierarchy from subclass to superclass

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Given three entities A, B and C where B extends A such as :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {
    private C c;
    //omitted source code

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_id", nullable = false)
    public C getC() {
       return c;
    }
    public void setC(C c){
       this.c=c;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B extends A {
    private Integer id;
    //omitted source code
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "c")
public class C {
    private Integer id;
    private String status;
    //omitted source code
}
```

How can I convert to following native SQL to HQL :

```
select b.* from b b_
inner join a a_ on a_.id=b_.id
inner join c c_ on a_.c_id=c_.id
where c_.status='ACCEPTED';
```

I tried the following : `select b from B b join b.c c where c.status = 'ACCEPTED'` however I get this exception :  `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: c of: B`. I thought Hibernate would resolve the superclass fields at runtime.

What I am trying to achieve here is to ascend the inheritance hierarchy starting exactly from `from B` and read the superclass `A` inner fields, in particular `c`. I wonder if this is doable in hibernate. Otherwise any alternative solution will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the visibility of the `C` instance variable inside `A`:

```
public class A {
    protected C c;
    //....
```

`protected` ensures the children of `A` (*and also other members in the same package where `A` is located*) to be able to directly access `c`, as it becomes an ***inherited variable***.

This way, `c` is visible from any `B` instance, leading to `bInstance.c` being valid. As a result, `hibernate` would identify **`select b from B b join b.c c`** as a valid command.